# SQL Server Full Text Search: Combine database records and physical files and maintain ranking

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search

Is it possible to perform a full text search, combined, on the file system and (multiple) table contents, at once?

Worth mentioning that we really need to keep the relevance ranking. Now we combine these results in code, but AFAIK, we cannot maintain the ranking in that approach.

Comment: Yes, for example the specs of Solr say: Full Text Search and database integration. I'm just wondering if SQL FTS + Windows Search provides this functionality as well. Would be very useful to us as well :-)

Comment: This may help :

[Using Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2008 across multiple tables, columns][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns