# SQL Server full-text search - many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm working on a project with SQL Server 2008 where I believe full-text search is the best way to go. I've been reading up on it as much as I can, and pretty much understand hos to set it up for a single table. However I'm not entirely sure how to set it up with my scenario - imagine the following table structure:

**Book**

```
- Id
- Title
- Description
```

**BookAuthor**

```
- BookId
- AuthorId
```

**Author**

```
- Id
- Name
```

As you can see, the database holds a table with books, and each book can have none, one or many authors. Each author can also be part of none, one or many books - i.e. the `Book` and `Author` tables have a many-to-many relationship, handled with the linking table `BookAuthor`.

What I want to accomplish at this point is a search tool to find matching books based on a search string the user provides. So if the user types in `Brown` I would want to find all books where either of the following columns contains the word `Brown`:

```
Book.Title
Book.Description
Author.Name
```

In essence, I want a result set of books, including both the book with the title `Brown Bear` and the books written by author `Dan Brown`. If there are any suggestions out there as to how I should set this up, I'd really appreciate your input!

*(as a side note, once I have this filtering working, the query result would also need to be sortable and pageable, handled via `@SortOrder`, `@PageIndex` and `@PageSize` passed into a Stored Procedure - but I guess that could be a separate question afterwards!)*

Comment: Why do you assuje full text search is a decent solution here? That toally looks like normal databae design for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2008 across multiple tables, columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns)

Comment: @TomTom Searching for "Brown" as above is just a simplified example of what I want to acheive. I need to be able to search for x number of words, and using LIKE will not work. We would also in the future want to be able to find rows that _almost_ match, and this will need full-text search (as far as I know).

Comment: @AdrianIftode Yes I've looked at that one, and I apologize if this is considered a duplicate. As the second answer there states though, I did not find that the accepted answer solves the problem. The other suggestion in the thread, to build an extra column in the Book-table with all the searchable data I assume would work, but be cumbersome and de-normalized, so I was curious if someone had any other suggestions.

Comment: @Iskariot unfortunately I can't undo the closing vote. I didn't know about the views, looks promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CONTAINS predicate can take a list of columns to search as its first argument; however, these columns must be from a single table.  You have a couple of options for getting around this limitation.  One option is that you can perform two separate searches, one on each table, and then UNION the results together.

```
select Id, Title from Book where contains([Description], 'brown')
union
select b.Id, b.Title
    from Book b inner join BookAuthor ba on b.Id = ba.BookId
        inner join Author a on a.Id=ba.AuthorId
    where contains([Name], 'brown')
```

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that [FTS indexes can be created on indexed views](http://versia.com/2008/02/sql-server-full-text-searching-across-multiple-tables/).  To do this, create an indexed view that contains both the Title field from the Book table and the Name field from the Author table, and then create a FTS index on both of these columns in the view. Then you can write queries against this view as follows:

```
select BookId, Title from vw_BooksAndAuthors 
where contains(([Description], [Name]), 'brown')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Joe! #1 I definitely see it would give the correct results - do you have any idea of the performance hit though with two queries and a union? Say that a book has both a Description that matches the search, and 5 separate authors that match - the same book would be found 6 times before they are "merged" with the union-statement.

Comment: Right, the performance of two queries and a union is definitely going to be worse than that of a single query.  There are some things you might want to consider for performance reasons, but before you invest the time in this, you should first establish that performance is going to be an issue in your app, and not waste time doing premature optimization.  If you do want to optimize performance, you could have a job that periodically runs and aggregates the content of the book and author tables into a single de-normalized table, and then query the single denomalized table.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that option too, to basically have a BookIndex-table that has the BookId, and one/many extra columns that have all the relevant searchable information, such as the Title, Description each Author's Name aggregated on one single row in that table. Then full-text-index that one, and join it to the Book-table when searching. I think I'll try your first suggestion above with the union, but if performance becomes an issue I'll go down this route instead. Thank you very much for your input!