# Word Co-occurrences in SQL - is this even possible?

Tags: sql, parsing, mysqli, split, unpivot

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
id | sentence                       | tags
1  | "people walk dogs in the park" | "pet park health"
2  | "I am allergic to dogs"        | "allergies health"
```

Is it possible to find the number co-occurrences between each tag word and each sentence word using an sql query?  It would be difficult because you would have to parse each tag and sentence entry.

It might look something like

```
select sentence_word,tag_word,count(id)
from
(select id,sentence_word
from table)A

join

(select id, tag_word
from table)B

on A.id=B.id
group by sentence_word,tag_word
```

except I know that the two sub-queries are not correct

Here are some sample results

```
 tag_word   | sentence_word  | count(id)
"walk"      |"pet"           |1
"health"    |"dogs"          |2
"allergies" |"dogs"          |1
```

Comment: Please, post sample results.

Comment: You will help yourself if you **normalize** the tags.

Comment: Sorry.  I do not have any results, I'm just trying to get a strategy to attack this problem.

Comment: By co-occurrences do you mean count of sentences who have common tag? E.g. in the above example it should return 2 for health and 1 for the rest?

Comment: Sorry @danihp, i just realized that I misunderstood what you said, I added some sample results.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I am actually referring to the individual words in the sentence and tags.  eg. health (tag) and dogs (word in sentence) co-occur twice

Comment: Can you provide the **complete** result based on your **two row** data sample?

Comment: if you consider using FULL TEXT INDEX on your tables, you might be able to do text search quite easily. I'll add a link that I've seen here in last couple of days ASAP

Comment: you might want to read about full-text search here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns?rq=1

Comment: What is your SQL flavor (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)? Can you use `stored procedures`?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following plan of action:

1. Move each of the two columns into their separate temporary databases
2. Call `stored procedure` ([like this one](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) for `MySQL`) to convert strings fields into columns
3. `CROSS JOIN` the two temporary tables
4. Run `COUNT DISTINCT` on the resulting data set

The above steps can combined into a stored procedure of its own.

Here is [an article on splitting](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for `SQL Server`.

In some SQL implementations splitting can be implemented as `user defined functions`.