# Fuzzy Match Values from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I am trying to use SQL Server FTS to create a fuzzy match between a name column in two different tables.  I have a FTS index on table A name field and want to find the match quality (Rank) of table b values that match table A on a fuzzy match.

```
Table A
Name
-------
My Senior High School
My Senior Higher Learning Place

Table B
--------------
My Senior HS
My Senior HS Learning Place
```

The hope is to take the top match (as close to 100%) as possible out of a the row match set.

I attempted to complete this using a CONTAINSTABLE query but I'm not sure how to parameterize the search in the FTS Indexed table with the values from the second table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns

Comment: Do you have Master Data Services installed on your server? If so, have you tried using the Similarity function? Works great for fuzzy matching and is configurable: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/02/05/finding-similar-strings-with-fuzzy-logic-functions-built-into-mds/