# Global application search design concern

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, search, asp.net-web-api2

I need to implement global application search. Here's how it must work:
We have an input, when a user starts typing, after three first are entered we must understand what table we must query, for example:

- if user typed first three chars as '888', we understand that we are
  searching for phone number, so we must query 'Phones' table in db,
  which contains input string
- if user typed first three chars as 'cJO' we understand that first
  char was c that means that we must query 'Contacts' table in db,
  which contains JO. The rusult must be as a hyperlink under the search
  input.
- other cases

So, if contact with name 'John' matches our search string, so result must be displayed as his name, and if we click on it we will be redirected on his profile page. Besides, in future there is 
a huge possibility that we should search in many tables by one search pattern, like: 'cMA' would mean that must search 'Contacts' and 'Cars' tables that contains 'MA'.
 
I have huge concerns on how to build search controller that will parse search string and dynamically decide what table to query. 
Will be very grateful for any design solutions

Used frameworks: angular2 + web api 2 + entity framework + sql server

Comment: Its hard to read, better to format in readable way

Comment: Sounds like you are going to down a design path that is not good. Why does the user need to know a bunch of codes to use a prefix for their search? You should either search all tables or provide a dropdown list of things to search for.

Comment: in some cases we should search for all tables, in case of some prefixes we should search only specific

Comment: Would use the search capabilites of the database, build a fulltext index and query the index.  [This question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns) should get you started...